# UFW Drop inbound ICMP requests from outside the local network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, firewall, ufw

How do I use ufw to drop inbound icmp traffic from outside my local network? Local network/mask is 10.0.2.0/24.

Comment: All icmp or just icmp echo requests (people trying to ping you)?

Comment: All inbound ICMP traffic from outside the local subnet